# Yii2 multiple models loop save error

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I've a table in which I have to save multiple data, in my controller I've implemented this action:

```
public function actionUpdateOrder($id){
    /*DA TESTARE*/
    //$result = 0;
    $result = true;
    $s = new Session;
    $model = new SlidersImages();
    if ($new_order = Yii::$app->request->post('order')) {
        //$s['us_model'] = 0;
        foreach ($new_order as $key => $value) {
            if ($model::find()->where(['slider_id' => $id, 'image_id' => $key])->all()) {
                 $s['image_'.$key] = $model;

                $model->display_order = $value;
                //$result = ($t = $model->update()) ? $result + $t : $result;
                $result = $model->save() && $result;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The data received are right but not the result, the only thing that the action do is to add new table row with `slider_id` and `image_id` equal to `NULL`, why the model doesn't save correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is when you call

`$model::find()->where(['slider_id' => $id, 'image_id' => $key])->all()`

you don't change the `$model` object itself. Essentially you are calling:

`SlidersImages::find()->where(['slider_id' => $id, 'image_id' => $key])->all()`

So, later when you call `$model->save()` you are saving a `$model` object with empty attributes (you only changed `display_order`)

My advise here: try to assign the result of the `->all()` call to the new var and then work with it:

```
public function actionUpdateOrder($id){
    /*DA TESTARE*/
    //$result = 0;
    $result = true;
    $s = new Session;
    if ($new_order = Yii::$app->request->post('order')) {
        //$s['us_model'] = 0;
        foreach ($new_order as $key => $value) {
            $models = SliderImages::find()->where(['slider_id' => $id, 'image_id' => $key])->all();
            if (count($models)) {
                // loop through $models and update them
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan Bes for the answer, the final solution I've adopted using your suggestion is as follows:
 `if ($model = SlidersImages::findOne(['slider_id' => $id, 'image_id' => $key])) {                    
                    $model->display_order = $value;
                    //$result = ($t = $model->update()) ? $result + $t : $result;
                    $result = $model->save() && $result;
                }`